# Sort by bash a text file by the first string (till '=')

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file for acronyms. Each line starts with the acronym (in uppercase), usually up to 4 letters, and then "=" and then the explanation. For example,

```
...

EST=Eastern Standard Time
OVS=Open vSwitch
IPMI=Intelligent Platform Management Interface 

...

IHV=Independent Hardware Vendor    
ISV=Independent Software Vendor

...
```

I want to sort this text file, in bash, by ascending order according to the acronym, which is the first string (till "=") in each line. Any suggestions as to the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried the `sort` command?

Comment: If the left hand are consistent a-zA-Z characters and the delimiter is the same, just use `sort` without a field separator.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `sort` command (`man sort`).  It has all manner of options for delimiting keys and establishing sorting parameters.

In your simple case:

```
sort --field-separator="=" < sort.list
```

would set the primary key to be everything up to the `=` and sort them in ascending order.

There is a "short form" for this, also (thanks @karafka!):

```
sort -t =
```

Check out `man sort` for details on sort order, using multiple keys and other options.

Comment: `sort -t= sort.list` will do

Comment: Agreed, but when dealing with people new to a command I prefer the user-friendly long-form to the expert-friendly short form.  Then a week from now the meaning of the flag is less likely to be forgotten.

Comment: @Greg yes, unfortunately delimiters are not standard across commands.  So, may not worth learning for causal users. However, redirection is not necessary.

Comment: Good point.  That is why I try to specify a source for definitive knowledge in the answer, in this case, the `man sort`.  But I agree it is worth knowing that there is a potentially more universal short name and I will amend the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene without delimiter `A1=` will appear before `A=`

Comment: @karafkfa: The seems to be saying that acronyms contain only uppercase letters.