# Sort a file alphabetically in place according to content until first "="

Tags: bash, sorting

I had asked about sorting a file alphabetically  according to content till fist `=`, and got an answer:
[Sort by bash a text file by the first string (till '=')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042420/sort-by-bash-a-text-file-by-the-first-string-till)

Now I have yet another question: 
Is there a way to do it "in place"?

What I mean is that indeed `sort -t= sort.list` does the job, and displays the sorted content on the screen; but `sort -t= sort.list > sort.list`
results in an empty `sort.list` file. Of course I can do:

```
sort -t= sort.list > sort1.list
```

and then

```
mv sort1.list sort.list
```

But is there a way to do it in one command?

Comment: learn to consult the programs documentation (and (to be fair) decipher the often dense, incomplete and/or exampleless description). `man sort` is worth the slog if you intend to be using linux for a lot of projects. Good luck.

Comment: The "full" `sort` documentation (`info sort`) actually has a bunch of useful examples.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the output filename like this:

```
sort -t= sort.list -o sort.list
```

and it won't overwrite your file. If your `sort` doesn't have this option, you have to use something like

```
sort -t= sort.list > sort.tmp && mv sort.tmp sort.list
```

... but it should have the option if it is [POSIX conformant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-o` option instead of writing to standard output.

```
sort -t= sort.list -o sort.list
```

It's not *really* in-place, but `sort` takes care of the temp-file dance internally.